# SQL - PL/SQL Writing a basic function and running it to query a result

Tags: plsql

I have the table `'Company'` populated with multiple tuples/rows.  One of which is Microsoft for the `'Company_name'` field and the `'City'` field is populated as Redmond.

I have compiled this PL/SQL file.

-- Create a function that will return the city where company X is located.
-- X will be the parameter supplied by the caller.
-- Test your function with the company of your choice.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION company_location_city(x IN company.company_name%TYPE)
return company.city%TYPE IS
  company_location company.city%TYPE;
BEGIN
  select city into company_location
  from company 
  where company_name = x;

  return company_location;
END;
```

and ran it with this line.

```
select company_location_city('Microsoft') from dual;
```

I get this error, and I don't understand what it is trying to tell me.  Of course we encountered select.

I am running the Oracle flavor.

> Error(12,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Also the query result showing an error should help.

> ORA-06575: Package or function COMPANY_LOCATION_CITY is in an invalid state
>   06575. 00000 -  "Package or function %s is in an invalid state"
>   *Cause:    A SQL statement references a PL/SQL function that is in an
>              invalid state. Oracle attempted to compile the function, but
>              detected errors.
>   *Action:   Check the SQL statement and the PL/SQL function for syntax
>              errors or incorrectly assigned, or missing, privileges for a
>              referenced object.
>   Error at Line: 16 Column: 8

[image: Ran in Oracle Sql Developer in the Worksheet Window]

Comment: You got pl\sql error but you ran sql query. How did you run this query? I mean did you use some IDE or sqlplus maybe?

Comment: I am using an IDE.  Sql Developer.

Comment: Oracle Sql Developer? So you should run the query in **SQL Worksheet** window. Did you do so?

Comment: Yes, I gave you an image to help.  Also, when I ran the select statement it gave an error as a query result.  Not sure what it means.

Comment: This is so weird, no changes and now it works.  All I did was make sure I highlighted the first block the function.  It compiled.  Then I highlighted the second block, and ran and it worked.  Why would something like that happen?

Comment: Just remove the function ddl code

Comment: Or add slash delimiter between function ddl code and sql query. You have mixed up sql and pl/sql , you should split them by delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **PLS** prefix of the error says that it is pl\sql engine error. Hence it means that your sql code was treated as pl\sql because of the function ddl code which is pl\sql. You mixed up sql and pl/sql , **you should split them by delimiter or remove one of the types of code**.